# How to install packages using "go get"

Tags: go

I recently set up Go but I'm unable to install packages using `go get`. I tried the advice posted for similar questions but had no luck.

I get the following for any package I try to install:

```
# cd .; git clone -- https://github.com/gorilla/mux /Users/Dan/Desktop/goworkspace/src/github.com/gorilla/mux
Cloning into '/Users/Dan/Desktop/goworkspace/src/github.com/gorilla/mux'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
package github.com/gorilla/mux: exit status 128
```

This is my Go env:

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/Dan/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/Dan/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/Dan/Desktop/goworkspace"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/j4/ntt6p0qn76v46thx2gnqxkm80000gn/T/go-build360206970=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

Comment: Another guess, you've configured git to use public key authentication, but haven't loaded the private key (also not Go related)

Comment: Thanks @JimB. The key files were missing for some reason but adding them back solved the issue. Assumed it was Go related as I just set it up and this was the first issue I encountered.

Answer (score 0):

If you had to fiddle with passphrase-protected private SSH key (to be added to an ssh-agent), that means you must have in `git config --global -l` a setting like:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

Since, as seen in [`golang/go` issue 6968](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6968), a `go get` would generally [use the HTTPS URL by default](https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https), and the repository [`github.com/gorilla/mux`](https://github.com/gorilla/mux) is a public one, that should have worked immediately, without having to use SSH keys at all.

So remove that setting.

If you need SSH, you can restrict for push operation only for GitHub, [as discussed here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/Zi-Kw2tbif8/XntDWd8TMrQJ):

```
[url "git@github.com/"]
    pushInsteadOf = https://github.com/
```